# show loading message while content loads

Tags: jquery

I know the following code would show a loading image when a button is clicked on the page:

```
   $.ajaxSetup ({  
         cache: false  
     });  
     var ajax_load = "<img src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";  


     var loadUrl = "ajax/load.php";  
     $("#load_basic").click(function(){  
         $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);  
     });
```

but what if I want this to happen soon as the page loads.  I dont want the user interaction of clicking a button to make the ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throw it inside the document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup ({  
     cache: false  
 });  
 var ajax_load = "<img src='img/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";  
 var loadUrl = "ajax/load.php";   
 $("#result").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){
   // now you are triggering click your self not waiting for uer to click,
   //although he may click to start an ajax request
    $("#load_basic").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling it from the $(document).ready() function.  You might also want to check out this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/gg681862.aspx), which adds a lot more to it.